# How to pass pointers to vector extensions in C

Tags: c, vector, vectorization

I'm trying to use GCC's vector extensions, **the exact code that I tried is**:

```
typedef float Vector4 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

void defVector(Vector4* v, float x,float y,float z,float w){
    v[0] = x;
    v[1] = y;
    v[2] = z;
    v[3] = w;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv){
    Vector4 a;
    defVector(&a, 1, 2, 3, 4); 
}
```

and keep getting errors:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Vector4 {aka __vector(4) float}’ from type ‘float’
v[0] = x;
```

Can't dereference it too or I get another error.
I would like to not copy the entire thing to the function stack every time I use it, and it's a necessity to make pointers to the return values like

```
int someFunc(Vector4 v, Vector4* r){
    ...
    r[0] = return_value;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried everything I know to access the values inside the funtion.
What I'm missing here?

Comment: What is `void defVector(Vector4* v, x,y,z,w)` even supposed to mean? Is this the real code?

Comment: @Lundin it is an example, but is close to real, it's supposed to help when you don't want to write all four subscripts (v[0]=this;v[1]=that ...)everywhere in the code. But suppose there's a function there, it's the same problem.

Comment: Show ***actual*** code, not something "close to real".

Comment: if is this the problem I forgot the floats in the question: void defVector(Vector4* v, float x, float y, float z, float w)

Comment: Please edit the question and make sure it contains the exact code causing the compiler error. See [mcve] for help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's example in which a local function gets a "[vector-extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)" pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef float Vector4 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

void defVector(Vector4 *v,float a, float b);

void defVector(Vector4 *v,float a, float b){
    v[0] = *(Vector4*)&a;
    v[1] = *(Vector4*)&b;

    a = *(float*)&v[0] + 1.2;
    b = *(float*)&v[1] + 2.1; 

    printf("%f,%f,%u",a,b,\
           (uint32_t)sizeof(Vector4)/(uint32_t)sizeof(float));
}

int main(void) {
    static Vector4 vectorA;
    static float x1 = 3.4;
    static float x2 = 4.3;

    defVector(&vectorA,x1,x2);
}
```

This code will print ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/osoqrffDnZhrz9cB)): `4.6,6.4,4` , so the value of two `float` were assigned to two units (being the number of units `sizeof(Vector4)/sizeof(float)`) of a `Vector4` type variable.